# is my Prim's MST implementation terse enough?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, graph

I did research because I want to learn Kruskal's and Prim's MSTs. I did research and after a solid understanding, I went to my textbook and got their libraries:

- https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/Edge.java.html
- https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/EdgeWeightedGraph.java.html

Here is my code, I've done some tests and it checks out on my end. I struggled a lot with finding an end point when inputted a start point, since when there is a dead end you kind of back track in the priority queue to the next best option.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.EdgeWeightedGraph;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Edge;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MinimumSpanningForest {
    public static EdgeWeightedGraph g;
    public static boolean[] visited;
    public static Queue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<Edge>();

    public static void edgeCompareTest() {
        Edge one = new Edge(1,2,2.0);
        Edge anotherOne = new Edge(1,3,4.0);
        Edge seven = new Edge(7,1,2.0);
        Edge anotherSeven = new Edge(7,4,1.0);

        System.out.println("one compared to one: " + one.compareTo(one));
        System.out.println("one compared to another one: " + one.compareTo(anotherOne));
        System.out.println("one compared to seven: " + one.compareTo(seven));
        System.out.println("seven compared to one: " + seven.compareTo(one));
        System.out.println("one compared to null: " + one.compareTo(null));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        g = new EdgeWeightedGraph(5,5);
//        g.addEdge(new Edge(0,1,0.3));
//        g.addEdge(new Edge(0,2,0.5));
//        g.addEdge(new Edge(2,3,1.2));
//        g.addEdge(new Edge(1,4,0.8));
        System.out.println(g);
        prim(g);



        //Queue<Edge> queue = new PriorityQueue<>((e1 , e2) -> e1.weight().compareTo(e2.weight()));
        for (int i = 0; i < g.E(); i++) {
            for(Edge e : g.adj(i)) {
                pq.add(e);
            }
        }

    }
    private static void qEdges(int vertex) {
        visited[vertex] = true;
        for (Edge edge : g.adj(vertex)) {
            if(!visited[edge.other(vertex)]) {
                pq.add(edge);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void prim(EdgeWeightedGraph g) {
        visited = new boolean[g.V()];
        int e = g.V() - 1;
        int edgeCount;
        double mstCost;
        int otherPt = 0;
        edgeCount = 0;
        mstCost = 0;
        Edge[] mstEdges = new Edge[e];
        qEdges(otherPt);

        while(!pq.isEmpty() && edgeCount != e) {
            Edge edge = pq.remove();
            otherPt = (!visited[edge.either()]) ? edge.either() : edge.other(edge.either());

            if(visited[otherPt]) {
                continue;
            }
            mstEdges[edgeCount++] = edge;
            mstCost += edge.weight();

            qEdges(otherPt);
        }

        if (edgeCount != mstEdges.length) {
            System.out.println("No MST exists!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is a MST in the following order of edges: ");
            for(Edge edge : mstEdges) {
                System.out.println(edge);
            }
            System.out.println("With a cost of " + mstCost);
        }
    }

    public static void kruskal(EdgeWeightedGraph g) {

    }
}
```

I did not do Kruskal's yet, but I figured that it would be best to make sure Prim's doesn't have any glaring fixes y'all would advise before I go ahead to Kruskals. Thanks.

Comment: "No MST exists!" - is it possible?

Comment: @vnp yes it is if the graph doesn't use all nodes/vertices. It cannot be disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing you hyperlinked Princeton *Algorithms, 4th Ed.* resources, I assume you know how to view their take of Prim's.
I do not understand your concern about *terse*ness.

There is one striking difference between the code you present for review and that of `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Edge` and `EdgeWeightedGraph` it uses:
Theirs is documented using the standard mechanism -
*Everything* public carries a doc comment. Even accessors.
→ Follow, or use something better.

For a class `MinimumSpanningForest`, a *static* member graph looks odd.
All three static member declarations in combination look state of a single *invocation*. Seeing `kruskal()` in addition to `prim()`, an invocation of some *graph algorithm* or *forest*~?
→ There should probably be an interface both Prim&Kruskal implement, each with its own *per instance* state.
A common base class could highlight commonalities.

(Finding Jarník/Prim/Dijkstra's algorithm the only one spelled out in a class `MinimumSpanningForest` is odd as it originally constructs a single spanning tree (containing the CC of the the initial node chosen) while [Kruskal's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) "naturally" arrives at the forest.)

I find the high-level description of Prim's easier to recognise in your take, while Princeton's may store less elements in the PQ.

I like names chosen for the purpose of what they name:
`shortestEdges` instead of `pq`,
`vertex` or `toAdd` instead of `otherPt` (while I can sort of see how it got "other" (would have preferred "unvisited"), what is "Pt" for?)
`qEdges` is overdoing *terseness* - `enqueueEdges` would do nicely.
(With a development tool supporting renaming, you don't need to *type* it that way.)
(I don't think I'd qualify *any* name local to `prim()` with mst.)
I'd comment *why* both vertices connected by an edge from the queue may be marked *visited* when only edges with one unvisited vertex are enqueued.

I like concerns separated:
I'd rather have an MST/MSF implementation return sets of edges, and specify&implement printing elsewhere.
To this end, and seeing the number of edges might not reach #vertices-1 when \$g\$ is not connected, I'd collect edges in a `List`.